# Customised Assertion in R

Tags: r, dataframe, testing, assertion

I have an excel sheet dataframe which contains 22 columns and multiple rows depends upon the output. There is one column named (let's say) `column_1`. Now I want to test this whole sheet using **asserts** but there is a condition, if `column_1` has a specific value `1` in any of it's row (let's say row 4), the assertion I wrote won't run for that whole row for all 22 columns, otherwise it will run the assertions for each column as usual.

Dummy Data:

```
column_1 | column_2 | column_3
NA | "House" | 12
NA | "Plot" | 34
NA | "Office" | 90
1 | "Villa" | 1008
...
...
...
```

Raw Logic

```
if (excel_sheet[["column_1"]] == "1") {

    # the assertion will **not** run for that specific row

} else {

    # the assertion will run for that specific row

    assert_numeric(x = excel_sheet[["column_1"]], any.missing = T, lower = 1, upper = 1)
    assert_numeric(x = excel_sheet[["column_2"]], any.missing = F, lower = 0, upper = 1)
    assert_numeric(x = excel_sheet[["column_3"]], any.missing = F)
    assert_character(x = excel_sheet[["column_4"]], any.missing = F)
    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear about your question? does your code run? does it stop? from which r-package are the ```assert_numeric / assert_character``` ? without some (dummy) data it is difficult to check. And when using if else, make sure the your if statement is between brackets ```if (excel_sheet[["column_1"]] == "1") {```

Comment: @Omniswitcher, i am looking for the code that meets my requirements. For now i have those assertions that are written in the else case of above question, but those assertions run for all rows. The package I am using is ```checkmate```.

Comment: @Omniswitcher I have added some dummy data in my question. Please have a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not familiar with the `checkmate` package and it's functions. But if I read the question correctly you want to

1. check for one specific column if it doesn't have a certain value.
2. if this is the case run the rest of your code.

taken the provided code it should be doable with a for loop:

```
for (i in excel_sheet$column_1){
  if(i != 1){
       # comment
    assert_numeric(x = i, any.missing = T, lower = 1, upper = 1)
    assert_numeric(x = i, any.missing = F, lower = 0, upper = 1)
    assert_numeric(x = i, any.missing = F)
    assert_character(x = i, any.missing = F)
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

**important**

1. be aware that comments need to be typed with a '#' not double slashes
2. as I read your code and my answer, it looks to me like the code will only focus on the specific cell `i` and not the row, do you want to change/assert a cell or the row?

Comment: Thank you @Omniswitcher. Your answer is very close to what i have already written. So in your answer, the for-loop is obtaining one single value of one single column.

What i have written is below:


`for (i in 1:nrow(excel_sheet))
{
assert_numeric(x = excel_sheet[["column_1"]][i], any.missing = F, lower = 0, upper = 1)
assert_character(x = excel_sheet[["column_4"]][i], any.missing = F)
}
`

Answer (score 0):

@Omniswitcher answer is the closest one. Here's my final solution.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(excel_sheet)) {

    if (excel_sheet[["column_1"]][i] != 1) {

        assert_numeric(x = excel_sheet[["column_2"]][i], any.missing = F, lower = 0, upper = 1)
        assert_numeric(x = excel_sheet[["column_3"]][i], any.missing = F)
        assert_character(x = excel_sheet[["column_4"]][i], any.missing = F)
        ...
        ...
        ...

    }

}
```